# What do arguments to the "source" command do?

Tags: linux, bash

I've encountered the following command:

```
source foo -c configs/foo.config
```

What is -c flag is actually may do here? foo is bash script, foo.config also looks like one.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `source` command is a bash-specific alias for the [POSIX-standardized command `.`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/dot.html). The specific usage you're asking about is mentioned by POSIX as an allowable extension:

> The KornShell version of dot takes optional arguments that are set to the positional parameters. This is a valid extension that allows a dot script to behave identically to a function.

Thus, when code read from `foo` is invoked, its `$1` will be `-c` and its `$2` will be `configs/foo.config`.

---

This is also explicitly documented if you run `help source` in bash:

> ```
> source: source filename [arguments]
>   Execute commands from a file in the current shell.
>
>   Read and execute commands from FILENAME in the current shell.  The
>   entries in $PATH are used to find the directory containing FILENAME.
>   If any ARGUMENTS are supplied, they become the positional parameters
>   when FILENAME is executed.
>
>   Exit Status:
>   Returns the status of the last command executed in FILENAME; fails if
>   FILENAME cannot be read.
> ```

Note the text above: **If any ARGUMENTS are supplied, they become the positional parameters when FILENAME is executed.**